# Why am I not getting the desired output

Tags: shell

This is the problem and, why am I not getting output as **Today is date(24/01/2024)** pls resolve this, and explain why am I not getting date in the below command  ?

```
ubuntu@ip-192.56.21.19:~$ date | echo "Today is"
Today is
```

I tried this but couldnot resolve this, help me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. For shell usage questions, see [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su].

Answer (score 2):

This is arguably off-topic for SO, but I'm treating it as a programming question about the shell.

You're feeding the date as input to `echo`, but `echo` doesn't do anything with its input; it's completely ignored. You can send anything you like into it and all you get back is whatever you put on the command line:

```
$ echo 'boo!' | echo hi
hi
$ echo hello </etc/passwd
hello
```

etc, etc, etc.

You can do what you want in a number of ways. For instance, you could simply echo the `Today is`  first and then call `date` afterward:

```
$ printf '%s ' 'Today is'; date
Today is Tue Jan 23 22:43:01 EST 2024
```

But most solutions would use *command substitution* to include the output of `date` as a string inside the command doing the echoing. For example:

```
$ printf 'Today is %s\n' "$(date)"
Today is Tue Jan 23 22:43:53 EST 2024
```

The `"$(date)"` construct runs `date` and is then replaced by whatever it outputs.

I used `printf` instead of `echo`, which is a best practice for shell programs; the behavior of `echo` is slightly inconsistent between shell implementations, and most of them don't strictly adhere to the POSIX specification. `printf` is much more consistent, and the use of format specifiers means you don't have to do as much interpolation, which otherwise might require miyying and matching types of quotation marks. You do have to supply your own newlines, but that also makes it easy to echo stuff without a newline, as in the first solution above.

If you want the date in a different format you can use the +*formatstring* parameter to `date`. Check out the [strftime(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) man page for all the field options, but to get dd/mm/yyy use `date +%d/%m/%Y`.

Answer (score 0):

try : `echo Today is $(date +%d/%m/%Y)`
your line dosen't work cause the a | b operator feed the a command with the b result
You need to print "Today is" followed by the result of the date command wich you format then